# Laravel - Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel without input file

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have implemented Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel with input file, this works fine.

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
   $path = $request->file('file');
    
     if (!is_file($path))
     {
        dd("file excel missing");
     }
    
     Excel::import(new ProductsSerialsImport,request()->file('file')); 
    
     return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'File updated!');
    
}

Route::post('products_serials/import', 'ProductsSerialsController@import')->name('products_serials.import');
```

I done something of this, but don't understand where I can receive excel file without pass through input file.

```
public function import(Request $request)
{

    $path = "storage/excel/file.xlsx";

    if(!File::exists($path)) {
        dd("missing excel file!");
    }

    Excel::import(new ProductsSerialsImport, $path);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'File updated!');
}
```

How I can update excel file from route => 'products_serials/import' skipping upload file through the input file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to passing the request()->file('file') to your import class?

Answer (score 0):

There's a constructor. from [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#constructor) it will be like this

**ProductsSerialImport.php**

```
class ProductsSerialImport implements ToCollection {
    private $file;

    public function __construct($file) 
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }
    
    public function collection(Collection $row)
    {
        foreach($row as $r) {
            Model::create(['name', $this->file]); // Just for example
        }
    }
}
```

**YourController.php**

```
Excel::import(new ProductsSerialsImport(request()->file('file')));
```